# Strange Youtube Search API behaviour

Tags: php, json, youtube-data-api

When using the youtube data ip I cannot retrieve a video id. I can use all other fields but get an error accessing the videoId field. The following:
    `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={api_key}&channelId=UCXuqSBlHAE6Xw-yeJA0Tunw&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=2`

returns

```
{
"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
"etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/ycDRkf40ZrOgEHl0cz-4b60EIFc\"",
"nextPageToken": "CAIQAA",
"regionCode": "GB",
"pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 3510,
 "resultsPerPage": 2
},
"items": [
{
"kind": "youtube#searchResult",
"etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/HOEmnNQHjX9o0bjBMiW0ipFEyl0\"",
"id": {
"kind": "youtube#video",
"videoId": "dkDq3JJ6IvM"
},
"snippet": {
"publishedAt": "2016-10-04T07:05:26.000Z",
"channelId": "UCXuqSBlHAE6Xw-yeJA0Tunw",
"title": "Best All-around Gaming Laptop? - MSI GS63VR Review",
"description": "The GS63VR from MSI is our first GTX 1060-equipped gaming laptop. And man, are we impressed... TunnelBear message: TunnelBear is the easy-to-use VPN ...",
"thumbnails": {
 "default": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dkDq3JJ6IvM/default.jpg",
  "width": 120,
  "height": 90
 },
 "medium": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dkDq3JJ6IvM/mqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 320,
  "height": 180
 },
 "high": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dkDq3JJ6IvM/hqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 480,
  "height": 360
 }
},
"channelTitle": "LinusTechTips",
"liveBroadcastContent": "none"
}
},
{
"kind": "youtube#searchResult",
"etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/qXo91IDtZrS-0G5AOWB--t3pR4Y\"",
"id": {
"kind": "youtube#video",
"videoId": "g7UX0nP70E0"
},
"snippet": {
"publishedAt": "2016-10-03T06:50:31.000Z",
"channelId": "UCXuqSBlHAE6Xw-yeJA0Tunw",
"title": "The best retro gaming experience ever?",
"description": "Controllers are truly a dime a dozen nowadays... But do these retro-inspired controllers, and their wireless adapters, stand out from the pack? iFixit link: Use offer ...",
"thumbnails": {
 "default": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/g7UX0nP70E0/default.jpg",
  "width": 120,
  "height": 90
 },
 "medium": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/g7UX0nP70E0/mqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 320,
  "height": 180
 },
 "high": {
  "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/g7UX0nP70E0/hqdefault.jpg",
  "width": 480,
  "height": 360
 }
},
"channelTitle": "LinusTechTips",
"liveBroadcastContent": "none"
}
}
]
}
```

Now if I 
    `$videos = json_decode($result)`

```
foreach($videos->items as $video)
    {
        print_r($video->id->videoId);

    }
```

I get an error

```
   [ErrorException]
   Undefined property: stdClass::$videoId
```

however
`print_r($video->id->kind)` returns the desired result

also `print_r($video->id)` returns:

```
   stdClass Object
   (
   [kind] => youtube#video
   [videoId] => dkDq3JJ6IvM
   )
```

Comment: For what it's worth, your code runs fine on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/gFgo6R).

Comment: I have found a work around, I have to `json_decode(json_encode(json_decode('YoutubeAPIURL))))`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my comment above wasn't the solution.

In actual fact the foreach loop was the issue for some reason:

```
 foreach($videos->items as $video)
    {
        print_r($video->id->videoId);
    }
```

This didn't work and resulted in the error. Simply replacing $video in the foreach loop with a different word (in this case item) solved it:

```
foreach($videos->items as $item)
    {
        print_r($item->id->videoId);
    }
```